# What is the simplest way to list which attached disks are encrypted (and which not) on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, encryption

An auditor is asking for proof that we've [encrypted all the disks](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/encrypting-data-at-rest/) on our AWS EC2 VPC. I'd like a way to list all the disks and whether they're [encrypted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html) or not.

I know I can build a report with the AWS [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeVolumes.html) (or [the CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html)) - but I was looking for a simpler approach than that, hopefully with the [console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console.html).

My question is: **What is the simplest way to list which attached disks are encrypted (and which not) on AWS?**

Comment: A dirty implementation would be pulling that data from the response of a simple `awscli` descrive-volumes command

Comment: thanks @Dawny33 - could you expand on that? Would it be specific to attached volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of non encrypted volumes you can run this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --region <your_region> --filter "Name=encrypted,Values=false" --query "length(Volumes[])"
```

`length` will return the length of the array `Volumes` flattened by the selection operator `[]` (more details on [JMESPath documentation](http://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html)).
As we filter the slection for non encrypted volumes (`--filter "Name=encrypted,Values=false"`) this should allow to demonstrate to the auditor the number is 0 not encrypted volumes.

Same filter can be applied in the console, in the ec2 page, under 'Elastic Block Store' => 'Volumes', type `Encrypted : Not Encrypted` to filter the view to non encrypted volumes only. you may add `Attachment Status : Attached` to list only attached volumes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html) you can run command like:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --region us-east-1
```

(feel free to set region you use)
and search for field in json output, named "encrypted"